# How to save more than 4kb of data on user's local storage using javascript?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, session-cookies, javascript

I need to find the way to save more than 4kb of data on user's cookies or any local storage. The problem is that i need a crossbrowser way and it should work at least on IE8? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Each localStorage instance (denoted by the origin website) has at most 5 megabytes.  This is more than enough space to store 4Kb.

Comment: IE 8 has an ability to save user's data in the localStorage. This means that you can save 5mb with crossbrowser way. If you want to save more that 5mb you will need to another storage or you can try to shrink data

Comment: Did you do any research first on LocalStorage?  If so, what specific questions about it did you run into that you might need help with.  It is not clear what your question is about since you seem to already know that cookies are limited in size and LocalStorage could meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Local Storage**.

It allows you to store a maximum of 5 MB.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('bar', 'myValue');
var value = localStorage.getItem('bar');
```

`value` is now "myValue".

Details: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

IE8+ and other leading browsers, Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Safari support Local Storage out of the box.

Try this if you want to store any other data types other than Strings.

```
localStorage.setItem('bar', JSON.stringify('myValue'));

var value = localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse('bar'));
```

`JSON.stringify` converts any data type into JSON objects and `JSON.parse` parses the data stored.